# Replacing letters in a string using two arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

```
    var str = "ajdisoiureenvmcnmvm"
    var arr1 = ["e","t","a","i","n","o","h","r","d","q","l","c","u","m","w","f","s","g","y","p","b","v","k","j","x","z"]
    var arr2 = ["m","i","e","n","v","r","d","j","s","o","u","c","b","a","f","g","h","k","l","p","q","t","w","x","z","y"]
```

What is the most efficient way of replacing the string such that if it contains an "m" replace it with "e", "i" with "t" and so on.

Comment: "Most efficient" in JavaScript tends to vary wildly according to which engines you use. Just make code that works. If you find a performance problem with it on a specific engine later, worry about it if/when that happens.

Comment: Can you change the structure of things? E.g., does it *have* to be two parallel arrays?

Comment: well I mean 26 lines of code is definitely not the most efficient way

Comment: @T.J.Crowder what so you mean

Comment: @ user: What makes you say that? Efficient by what standard?

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure there is a faster way, maybe with regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be self explanatory and relatively efficient.

```
str = str.split("")
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str[i];
    var j = arr1.indexOf(c);
    str[i] = arr2[j];
}
str = str.join("");
```

I'd use a mapping for this kind of thing though.

Comment: I think it may be this: `str[i] = arr2[j];`

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. This doesn't work. I wonder why @user3184807 said it does.

Comment: Strings in JS are immutable so you can't do `str[i] = arr2[j];`.

Comment: using a tmp string and a appending it, will work but it's probably slowish. joining an array is hardly going to be any quicker though

Comment: what if indexOf return -1

Comment: assuming `arr1` is an array of length 26 and str is a alphabetical string

Comment: This doesn't necessarily preserve character order for all possible inputs which the OP implied was a requirement since they wanted to "replace" one character with another. Also doesn't have error checking to even see if a source char exists.

Comment: Was in middle of changing it to what I suggested you do.

Comment: @Niall: +1 *"using a tmp string and a appending it, will work but it's probably slowish. joining an array is hardly going to be any quicker though"* Indeed, it appears to be slower, on Firefox and Chrome (pretty much a tie with Opera): http://jsperf.com/str-concat-vs-replace-w-func But they both beat calling a function via `replace`. Not that it's likely to matter in the real world, but they do, and the code is easier to read, too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with `map`:

```
function encode (string) {
  return string.split("").map(function (letter) {
    return arr1[arr2.indexOf(letter)];
  }).join("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your definition of "efficient." With that structure, it's quite hard to be efficient. But something like this is *functional* and short:

```
var rex = new RegExp("[" + arr1.join("") + "]", "g");
var result = str.replace(rex, function(letter) {
    var index = arr1.indexOf(letter);
    return index === -1 ? letter : arr2[index];
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/OlenoXe/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/OlenoXe/1/edit)

There, we create a regular expression using a character class to match each of the source characters, then do a replacement operation using a function to look up the replacement (if any) from the arrays.

Now, if you can change the structure, there are better ways, like using a map rather than `arr1.indexOf`. E.g.:

```
var map = {
    "e": "m",
    "t": "i",
    "a": "e",
    // ...
};
```

Then (this uses ES5's `Object.keys`, which can be shimmed if needed):

```
var rex = new RegExp("[" + Object.keys(map).join("") + "]", "g");
var result = str.replace(rex, function(letter) {
    return map[letter] || letter;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "ajdisoiureenvmcnmvm"
var arr1 = ["e","t","a","i","n","o","h","r","d","q","l","c","u","m","w","f","s","g","y","p","b","v","k","j","x","z"]
var arr2 = ["m","i","e","n","v","r","d","j","s","o","u","c","b","a","f","g","h","k","l","p","q","t","w","x","z","y"]

newStr = str.split("");
for (var i=0, len=newStr.length; i<len; i++)
{
    index = arr2.indexOf(newStr[i]);
    if(index>=0)
        newStr[i] = arr1[index];
}
str = newStr.join("");
console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably a more straight forward approach is to put the original string into an array first so you can manipulate it more easily character by character:

```
var arr1 = ["e","t","a","i","n","o","h","r","d","q","l","c","u","m","w","f","s","g","y","p","b","v","k","j","x","z"];
var arr2 = ["m","i","e","n","v","r","d","j","s","o","u","c","b","a","f","g","h","k","l","p","q","t","w","x","z","y"];
var str = "ajdisoiureenvmcnmvm";
var data = str.split(""), index;
for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    index = str.indexOf(arr2[i]);
    if (index >= 0) {
        data[index] = arr1[i];
    }
}
// build the string back again
str = data.join("");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/fAQTe/

Comment: you'd be better off doing `str.split("")`

Answer (score 0):

I knew you don't ask for the way to do by shell script, but it will give you the feeling how easily it can be done by tr command in this special request.

```
echo "ajdisoiureenvmcnmvm" |tr "etainohrdqlcumwfsgypbvkjxz" "mienvrdjsoucbafghklpqtwxzy"

exsnhrnbjmmvtacvata
```